# How to make a relationship to two views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am creating a website in which i am already created two view (1. Category 2. Location) , now i am created the taxonomy for Location and in Category view  I am exposed the Location Taxonomy,,, and in Location View here also i am exposed the view-block,,, so the Taxonomy is same in both views,, Now I want to know that if I will select the Category view Location  then automatically Location will be select in @nd view (Location view),,,

Plz provide any suggestion ..?

Here is the image of Location View (1st pic):
[image]

Checkbox (2nd pic):

[image]

So if i will select the Bangalore in Search Menu in 1st pic,  then the Bangalore will automatically selected in 2nd pic (View) (i.e. in checkbox).

Comment: Why do you need to pick the same city twice?

Comment: my requirement is this, that if i select from 1st view it will automatically selectedc in 2nd view

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both views are showing the same page, it could be accomplished using something like this:

- Using [Views Field Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), create the second view as a child field of the first

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

- pass the arguments (instructions included in module) to the second view to ensure it is getting the correctly information
- use [Views Auto Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh), [Views Flag Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_flag_refresh) or [Block Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_refresh) - depending the exact set up you have and want to refresh the second view

Comment: No its not working

Comment: What specifically is not working?